# AssertError when fitting a model

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a small data set, it has less than `2000` rows. I am trying to fit a `LinearRegressionModel` using `ML`, well the data set has only one `feature` (which I already normalized), after the model was fitted, I evaluated it using a `RegressionEvaluator` and measuring metrics `R2` and `RMSE`. Then I noticed the error was high, and hence decided to create more artificial features, in order to describe better the phenomena. To achieve this I created the following `UDF` (notice I check it works).

```
numberFeatures = 12

def addFeatures(value):
    v = value.toArray()[0]
    return Vectors.dense([v ** (1.0 / x) for x in xrange(2, 10)] + 
                         [v ** x for x in xrange(1, numberFeatures)])

addFeaturesUDF = udf(addFeatures, VectorUDT())

# Here I test it
print(addFeatures(Vectors.dense(2)))

# [1.0,0.666666666667,0.5,0.4,0.333333333333,0.285714285714,0.25,0.222222222222,2.0,4.0,8.0,16.0,32.0,64.0,128.0,256.0,512.0,1024.0,2048.0]
```

After this I modify my `DataFrame` to add more features, using `addFeaturesUDF`, I can show it bellow.

```
dtBoosted = dt.withColumn("features", addFeaturesUDF(col("features")))
dtBoosted.show(5)
#+--------+-----+----------+--------------------+
#|    date|price|   feature|            features|
#+--------+-----+----------+--------------------+
#|733946.0| 9.92|[733946.0]|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|
#|733948.0| 8.05|[733948.0]|[4.88997555012224...|
#|733949.0| 8.05|[733949.0]|[7.33496332518337...|
#|733950.0| 7.91|[733950.0]|[9.77995110024449...|
#|733951.0| 7.91|[733951.0]|[0.00122249388753...|
#+--------+-----+----------+--------------------+
# only showing top 5 rows
```

And works, but when I attempt to fit the model it shows an [AssertError](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ed6939ff72417c70764a).

```
dtTrain, dtValidation = dtBoosted.randomSplit([0.75, 0.25], seed=107)
lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=100, labelCol="price", featuresCol="features")
lrm = lr.fit(dtTrain)
```

What is the problem? What am I doing wrong? It worked with one feature and some other features!

Comment: Looks like numerical issue than anything else.

Comment: @zero323 Is there any other data type I can use?